# Excel Conditional Formatting that uses different color everywhere a specified value is found outside the highlighting field

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-formatting

I was given a Project Management template that highlights the dates within a date range. The problem is that conditional formatting will highlight all the selected cells the same. My supervisor wants it to be a different color according to the person who is assigned the row. Currently, there are almost a hundred rows in this one sample with at least 10 people to be assigned. Here is a picture of the first portion of the sheet:

[A1 to L13 of Excel spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F53hu.jpg)

The conditional formatting is as follows:

```
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK($D7)),$D7<==F$5,$E7>==F$5)
```

and it is set to apply to

```
=$f$7:$BI$91
```

Right now, it uses blue to highlight every assigned set of cells in the F7 - B91 block. However, it is the same color whether the row is assigned to Bob or Cal or Dave . . .

I know I will have to create a set of "keys" to assign the color to a name so that it will use blue for Bob, red for Cal, green for Dave, etc. However, I don't know how to get it to do that for all cells in a row that match the person's name. I could make 10 IF rules for each row . . .  but I know there is a better way.

Note: I need to do this without using VBA.

Comment: You'll need to make a condition for each person. You may want a helper table with the names of everyone somewhere that the conditions refers to instead of hard coding names in each condition

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad - I don't mind a new rule/condition for each person, but I don't know how to do it. I need to know how to apply the highlighting to the rows where the person's name is in the 'B' column and not in the other rows.

Comment: Add a condition to your `AND` statement, something like: `=AND(NOT(ISBLANK($D7)),$D7<==F$5,$E7>==F$5,$B7="name")`

Comment: Sorry for the late response, @cybernetic.nomad . . . but that worked. Thank you!